# What file system can I use on SD Cards?

Tags: external-sd, file-system, tablet, usb-storage

I stupidly changed my new SD cards file system to NTFS for using with my laptops and my Android tablet. Now I realize my tablet doesn't want to see the card when I put it in. And now I bought 2 USB's and notice they have FAT32 file system on them.

Which file system will work for each storage and will be compatible with all my devices?

Comment: TYPING IN ALL CAPS SIGNIFIES YELLING. Please stop.

Comment: Welcome To Android SE. Please, not all caps. Its annoying

Answer (score 0):

On Android I would use exFAT, it has fewer limits and is supported to read and write by most platforms including Linux, Android, Osx and obviously Windows. You might need a couple of lines of commands on linux, not a big deal.

For Linux users:

```
apt(or yum) install fuse exfat-utils
```

Some desktop environments might have exFAT support by default though.

Answer (score -1):

Fat32 and Fat64 are used for microSDHC and MicroSDXC cards, which are normally the ones used in mobile devices such as phones or tablets. So either fat32 or fat64 will work for your tablet. Fat32 is fine for the usb as well

Comment: Although, does your tablet have a USB port that you can even connect a flash drive to?

Comment: FAT64 does not exist. You definitely mean exFAT (which is often not supported on older devices).

Comment: Exfat and fat64 are the same thing, just a different way to say it, and I'm aware that most older devices don't support it

Comment: But some newer devices DO support it (such as the phone I have, the LG K7)

Comment: Yes, nearly all newer devices support exFAT. By the way: [exFAT or FAT64?](http://superuser.com/a/1089138/468430)

Comment: I was literally just reading that question as you sent me it lol, and thanks for the correction, I get it now.